# How to add content to elements, that created after page loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have div that created dynamically, and I want to add some elements into it when its loaded. jQuery `.load()` and `.live()` didn't help me.

```
$('div#mydiv').load(function(){
   $(this).html('loaded!');
});
```

Comment: where's the div created? Can't you add the `.html()` there?

Comment: I deal with it. Thank you Manuel. I went too hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an event for click in ready section:

```
$('input').live( 'click', function(){
        alert("!");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know what the problem is without more context. If you can, post a more complete snippet of what you're trying to do.

From what you've posted so far, I take it the `#myDiv` div is not present in the initial HTML of the page. So I see two possibilities:

- You have some other JS that's creating the element (eg. `$('#foo').append('<div id="myDiv"></div>')`. Then the element will be available and 'there' as soon as your code appends it to some element in the page. So in this case, assuming element `#foo` is already in the DOM, you could do something like `$('#myDiv').text('Loaded!')` on the next line.
- You're loading the element as part of an AJAX call (ie over the network). If you're using [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with an element (`$('#foo').load('/someurl')`) you can add another parameter with a callback function which will be called once the content has been loaded. If you're using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or its shorthand friends (`$.get`, `$.post`, etc.), and appending/creating content dynamically from its `success` or `complete` callbacks, see the previous bullet point.

Hope this helps. Without more context, it's hard to give a more specific answer to your question, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the external file and then inserting your code in the callback:

```
$('#mydiv').load('myfolder/myfile.html', function() {
    $('#mynewdiv').html('loaded');
});
```

If all else fails, try using $.Ajax to load the file, and the complete handler to insert your content.